# Why "absolute" instead of "absolutam"?

Tags: grammar-choice, new-latin, translation-explanation, mathematics

There's a famous piece of mathematics by János Bolyai, originally published in Latin, under the title [*Scientiam Spatii Absolute Veram Exhibens: A Veritate Aut Falsitate Axiomatis XI Euclidei, A Priori Haud Unquam Decidenda, Independentem: Adjecta Ad Casum Falsitatis Quadratura Circuli Geometrica*](http://real-eod.mtak.hu/1708/1/ioannisbolyaide00akadgoog.pdf).

An English translation was eventually published under the title [*The Science Absolute of Space: Independent of the Truth or Falsity of Euclid's Axiom 11 (which can never be decided a priori)*](http://real-eod.mtak.hu/2790/1/scienceabsolute00bolygoog.pdf).

Most of the grammar makes sense to me, even if the meanings of some words are not what my Classical training expected.

But what is *absolute* doing here? The English translation makes it sound like it modifies *scientiam*, but then surely it would need to be an accusative adjective, not an adverb? The best I can come up with is that it's, literally, "showing off independently the science of space" (with an adverb modifying *exhibens*), but that's very different from the published English translation.

(Bonus question: since the English translation doesn't include the subsubtitle, what does it mean for a geometric squaring of the circle to be *adjecta* to the result of falsehood?)

Comment: If it's an adverb it must go with *exhibens*, I guess.

Comment: "absolutely true, " maybe?

Comment: Looks like the English title is a rather loose translation. Unless you are taking "scientia vera" to mean "science", a more literal translation of the portion before the colon is "Showing that the science of space is absolutely true". You have also left off the initial portion of the title ("Ioannis Bolyai de Bolya Appendix"); the word "exhibens" evidently modifies "appendix". The work is "An appendix of I. B. de B. showing that the science of space is absolutely true..." etc. EDIT: per @Cairnarvon, one could also have "absolutely showing that the science of space is true."

Comment: Also: thanks for this question -- I'm a mathematician by training, and that looks like a very interesting book! I've downloaded the PDF and intend to read it.

Comment: @MPW Oh, I left out the "Appendix" part because it seems common enough for book titles to leave the noun implicit. For example, Caesar's books on the Gallic Wars are often cited as De Bello Gallico, leaving out the Commentarii. But if it's important to the translation to have an explicit noun there, I can edit it in.

Comment: I rescind my earlier comment. If you read the introduction, it really ought to be something like *scientiam spatii absolutam esse veram*. I'm not a mathematician, so I could be wrong on this, but it seems the translator was saying that Bolyai's work differs from Euclidean space by allowing human imperfection. Is that right? I know post-Classical writers are a bit more carefree in word order, but it still feels a bit more like a mistake (outside poetry).